# Modelagem de Relatórios no ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, mvc

Tenho vários relatórios na empresa, e preciso migrar eles de webforms para MVC. Minha dúvida é.. preciso criar um modelo para cada relatório? Isso é correto? Se não, como posso fazer?

Por exemplo:

Tenho um relatório que deve listar a movimentação (produção) diária de um funcionário do almoxarifado da empresa...os dados que serão retornados são:

```
Usuário (Login no sistema):  
Nome do Usuário: 
Quantidade de requisições atendidas: 
Quantidade de itens atendidos:
```

Hoje, dentro do meu sistema, eu tenho o objeto Usuario, seria interessante modelar este relatório? Sendo que só vou utiliza-lo neste local.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal seria você criar ViewModels para os seus relatórios, mas por questão de performance e alocação de recursos é melhor manter as consultas no banco de dados. O exemplo que você passou é um caso simples e a query não seria muito pesada, dependendo do volume.

Porém pode haver situações em que pelo volume de dados e ou o envolvimento de diversos schemas, databases e filtros mais complexos, você precise utilizar views e até mesmo tabelas auxiliares apenas para armazenar a massa gerada para a exibição de outros relatórios.

Particularmente, mesmo para os relatórios no ReportViewer, procuro manter todas as consultas dos DataSource em Stored Procedures. Facilita a manutenção e reuso, no caso de migrações como a sua, é metade do caminho.

A ViewModel para o seu exemplo poderia ser assim:

```
public class ProducaoViewModel {
   [Display(Name="Usuário (Login no sistema)")]
   public string LoginUsuario {get; set;}

   [Display(Name="Nome do Usuário")]
   public string NomeUsuario {get; set;}

   [Display(Name="Quantidade de requisições atendidas")]
   public int QtdRequisicoesAtendidas {get; set;} 

   [Display(Name="Quantidade de itens atendidos")]
   public int QtdItensAtendidos {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Mas no caso, eu teria que criar em um arquivo esta ViewModel? Ou posso adiciona-la a uma classe já existente na aplicação?

Comment: Veja que a `ProducaoViewModel` já é uma classe. Não é recomendado ter várias classes em um único arquivo por questões de boas práticas. Aconselho além de criar um arquivo para ela, adicionar um pasta "ViewModels" para agrupá-las em um `namespace`.